# Avoiding float rounding imprecision

Tags: precision, floating-accuracy

When doing division with floating point numbers, I often get imprecisions (such as `5.000000001`, etc).

Is there a way to do division without getting floating point imprecision problem when using floating point numbers?
Maybe there are better alternatives that avoid it?

Thank you in advance for all answers!

Comment: Why not just fix the source of the problem and stop using floating point math? You can multiply your numbers by 10 in this example and get the correct result. Although the result you get is 10x more than what it should be, it's still 1000x more accurate than using floating point math.

Comment: That should never happen if all your floats have `.0` fractions and you're just adding and subtracting. You only lose precision when you perform division and get fractions.

Comment: There's no way to know if you've lost precision, because you don't know what the correct result should be. For example, `2.99999` would be the correct result if you do `2.0 + 0.99999`, but it's the wrong result if you do `6.0 / 2.0`

Comment: Just round stuff appropriately before displaying it.  Your initial numbers have two significant digits.  Make your output have the same with .toPrecision or .toFixed

Comment: @Barmar yeah, the problem is with fractions, I wrote as addition and subtraction just to make my message more clear. I edited it now. Is there still a way, because I am only doing multiplication and division?

Comment: Using the floating point representation of real numbers your problem does not have a solution because the floating point representation is the problem.
Read more on http://floating-point.gui.de

Comment: You cannot know if the result has lost precision because you cannot know what is the exact expected value (you need to know it in order to detect the loss of precision). If you could know the exact expected value then you do not have this problem in the first place.

Comment: There is no general solution for “fixing” the problems that occur with **any** computed arithmetic, whether it is floating-point, fixed-point, integer, rational (fractions), symbolic, or other. Useful procedures are application-specific.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't find such "imprecisions", and even if you could, you wouldn't be able to fix them. For instance there is simply no way to represent 0.1 exactly as a float. This is not a bug, it's just how floating point numbers work (in any language), you just have to work your way around it.

Here are a few workarounds:

- Only use integers, as they are not subject to rounding errors (as long as they are not too big). For instance if you want to deal with financial amounts with only two digits after the decimal point, you should store your amounts in cents, not in euros/dollars/..., in order to only deal with integers.
- If you want to use arbitrary fractions, you should use a library designed for that. There are surely many such libraries. Or you can write your own, where a fraction a/b is represented as `{numerator: a, denominator: b}` (where `a` and `b` are integers, so no rounding errors) and then you implement addition, multiplication, equality, ..., on this representation, taking care of only manipulating integers.
- If you need to use arbitrary floating point numbers (for instance you're writing a function that detects collisions of two moving shapes), simply remember that you should *never* use equality. Equality is simply meaningless for arbitrary floating points numbers. You can use instead something like `Math.abs(b - a) < epsilon` where `epsilon` is chosen in a way that fits your application.

Comment: Re “Only use integers, as they are not subject to rounding errors (as long as they are not too big)”: On June 6, 2014, the closing price of Apple stock was 64557 cents per share. Integer arithmetic calculates the split-adjusted price as 9222 cents per share, but the current answer is about 9222.428571 cents per share. Integer arithmetic is subject to rounding errors.

Comment: Re “Equality is simply meaningless for arbitrary floating points numbers”: People generally do not compute arbitrary floating-point numbers; they compute numbers that are meaningful for their purposes. Functions without derivatives of modest magnitudes (which includes testing for equality, as it is discontinuous) are indeed difficult to deal with in floating-point arithmetic, but it is not correct to say they are always meaningless. E.g., testing whether a function argument is at a singularity may be meaningful.

Comment: "but the current answer is about 9222.428571 cents per share. Integer arithmetic is subject to rounding errors." I have no idea what you are talking about, 9222.428571 is not an integer, so you're not doing integer arithmetic.

Comment: "People generally do not compute arbitrary floating-point numbers" They absolutely do. For instance if you use requestAnimationFrame to compute an animation, the time from the previous frame to the current frame is an arbitrary floating point number, so everything you compute from that will also be (unless you round it, but there is no reason to, arbitrary floating point numbers are fine).

Comment: "E.g., testing whether a function argument is at a singularity may be meaningful." I am not at all convinced about that. For instance if you don't want to divide by 0, you probably don't want to divide by 0.1+0.2-0.3 either, even though it is not equal to 0.

Comment: Re “I have no idea what you are talking about, 9222.428571 is not an integer, so you're not doing integer arithmetic.”: Integer arithmetic for 64557 divided by 7 produces 9222. That answer is not the correct real-number arithmetic result, because it has been rounded toward zero. It is false to state integer arithmetic is not subject to rounding errors.

Comment: If you need arbitrary divisions of integers, see my second point about fractions. Integer arithmetic is when you only do operations that are supposed to produce integers.